# example.com/en/drive is redirecting to example.com/en

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem with redirection using .htaccess
When I hit example.com/en/drive it is redirecting to example.com/en/.
similary when i use with index.php "example.com/en/drive/index.php" it is working fine.

htaccess code is look like this

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex home.html index.htm index.html index.php
```

Any solution? please help. tahnks

Comment: try in incognito mode

Comment: I am testing this on 4 different PCs and/or MACs. Same issue

Comment: any other rules in .htaccess?

Comment: I have deleted all and tried with this code only, issue is same.

Comment: tried in private mode?

Comment: Yes same problem.